# Using Powershell to update users home directory

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell

I am trying to change the home directory path to a bunch of users.

I wrote a script in Ppowershell which should change the path the username like so:

```
\\serverName\shareName\$_.SamAccountName
```

The problem is that I get the DistinguishedName instead of the SamAccountName like so:

```
\\serverName\shareName\CN=UserName,OU=OuName,DC=domainName,dc=local
```

This is the script I wrote:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=XX,dc=domainName,dc=local' | ForEach-Object {
Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory "\\serverName\shareName\$_.SamAccountName"
}
```

Can anyone see why this is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of the way Powershell handles variables in quotes. Basically, rather than getting

```
$_.SamAccountName
```

You were actually getting

```
$_ + "SamAccountName"
```

To resolve this simply use the following method to encapsulate your variables:

```
Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory "\\serverName\shareName\$($_.SamAccountName)"
```

Update: @JScott has informed me that this method is called a ["subexpression"](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = Get-Content C:\temp\homedir\test.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $h = Get-ADUser $user -Properties * | select-object -expandproperty cn
    Set-ADUser $H -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory "\\my.domain.com\myserver\homedirs\$H"  
}
```

Comment: This needs explanation.